# How to capture inserting terminal to cradle

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

How to capture inserting terminal to cradle and make this tests?

i need to check 3 things:

```
1. if the terminal is in the cradle
2. if i got IP
3. if there is connection to my WebService
```

and after this, i need to transfer data between my WebService to the terminal (Windows-mobile 6.5)

how i can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a namespace Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status

In there you can find relevant information about your device.

For example, I have used the following snippet to know if an active desktop connection is present.

```
Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.SystemState.ConnectionsDesktopCount <= 0
```

Also there is this property, never used it.

```
Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.SystemState.CradlePresent
```

For the IP part.

```
//Get Device Name
var deviceName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
 //Get IP Address
IPHostEntry _ipHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(deviceName);
var IpAddress = _ipHost.AddressList[0].ToString();
```

For the connection to your webservice, you can create bool or int simple method to test if it is available.

Webservice

```
bool IsAvailable()
{
return true;
}
```

You just need to call the webservice.